# Сортировка ассоциативного массива по ключу

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет!)В php не силен)попалась такая задача:
написать функцию сортировки массива $TH, такую чтоб можно было на вход подать имя ключа и он по его значению отсортировал массив $TH
Подскажите каким образом можно решить задачу?

```
$m = array('a'=>'Honda','b'=>'Hummer','c'=>'BMW','d'=>'Toyota');
$s = array('a'=>'AH','b'=>'TU-144','c'=>'Boing','d'=>'СУ'); 
$t = array('a'=>'Тигр','b'=>'Пантера','c'=>'Т-34','d'=>'Волга'); 
$k = array('a'=>'Кузнецов','b'=>'Ямато','c'=>'Ясень','d'=>'Петропавловск');
$TH = array($m, $s, $t, $k);
```

Comment: что значит `на вход подать имя ключа и он по его значению отсортировал массив $TH` ? как это вообще должно выглядеть?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вот так, только на php, а не на js: `f = (arr, key) => arr.sort((x, y) => (x[key]>y[key]) - (x[key]<y[key]));
f([{a:7},{a:3},{a:1}], 'a')`

Answer (score 2):

Если имеется в виду по ключам `a,b,c,d`, то так?

```
$sortBy = "b";
usort($TH, function($l, $r) use ($sortBy){
                return strcmp($l[$sortBy], $r[$sortBy]);
            });

print_r($TH);
```

Comment: @br3t  это артефакты копирования кода из `mcedit`, поправил